# I can SSH into EC2 but ping results in timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, nginx, amazon-ec2

I uploaded a nodejs file that crashed the server due to an infinite loop. In a panic, I stopped the EC2 instance and started it again. This gave me a new IP address.

I updated the registrar details for the domain name with the new IP. When visiting the IP in the browser, I saw the NGinx welcome screen.

I then changed the conf file for the sites-available/domain.com, to add the new IP in the server block redirect. After doing this, the site timesout.

I tried removing the IP from the sites-available/domain.com and still the site timesout and I cannot even ping the IP or see the Nginx welcome page.

When trying the following

```
sudo nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

I get this error:

```
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:443 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:443 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:443 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:443 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:443 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
```

So I ran

```
grep -r listen /etc/nginx/*
```

I could see that the default and the domain.com 'sites-available' were both listening on port 80, 443 etc.

I deleted the default file from sites-available and restarted nginx. Now I only see the domain.com listening on port 80, 443 etc.

**Still**, nothing is loading when pinging the IP or the domain name in the browser or in terminal. I can ssh though.

I've also restarted UFW and ensured I enable Nginx Full etc., it's not a firewall issue. It's something to do with Nginx, I'm 99% sure.

**EDIT**
I should add that this is not a UFW issue. That's working fine and allows NGINX Full, as well as HTTP and HTTPS

Additionally, when I visit the server IP address in the browser, I am redirected to the domain name, but very very slowly. Then I get a timeout. So something is happening...

Please help, I've tried everything reasonable that I've found from hours of googling!

Comment: Note that you can create Elastic IPs and associate them with EC2 instances so that your public IP will be stable.

Comment: Yeah, I read after my mistake. I'll be setting that up next! Thank you

Comment: It's impossible to diagnose from your description.  "ping" is a specific ICMP thing, it's not a good term to use for general network requests.  It sounds like you're describing making HTTP requests.  "to add the new IP in the server block redirect" you really don't need to do that.  For many years, the same IP is used to serve many different domain names.  "when I visit the server IP address in the browser" similarly and for the same reason that isn't functionality that you need to support.

Comment: thanks for letting me me know about the IP address. Regarding the ping, I'm referring to typing in terminal 'ping domain[dot]com' and typing in the url into a browser. Both methods timeout. The browser does, however, redirect me to the correct https://www.domain[dot]com, if I type in domain.com, so something is working on the nginx side. Do you think it's due to stopping the instance and something has broken in nginx?

Comment: Your DNS entry for the domain name is almost certainly not updated yet, or updated incorrectly.  What does nslookup/dig show?

Comment: @AnonCoward nslookup shows the old IP, Dig shows the new IP. Thing is, why does typing the new IP in the URL bar of the browser update to show the domain name and redirect to the https version of it, if the DNS hasn't updated?

Comment: That has nothing to do with DNS.  Your webserver is configured to respond to a request with a Host header to redirect to the domain name.  Then the browser tries to follow the query, using the wrong IP because of the misconfigured domain name, and it times out.

Comment: @AnonCoward I hope it's just a DNS propagation issue but when I check dns propogation sites, I do see the new IP listed in all but 2 locations

Comment: You're right, I've tested on my cell - a different ISP - and I see the domain name loading just fine. You have saved me making a real mess of things. THANK YOU SO MUCH!